# Multiple Form(each with action and model attribute) in single jsp with spring webmvc 4.0.6

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc

My web application is based on Spring Web MVC 4.0.6 for front end, business and service logic, Hibernate for ORM (persistence), and JSP as view technology.

I have one JSP page which has multiple forms. Each form has its own action, model attribute mapped to respective form bean. When I trigger either of the actions, say login, by submitting associated form, I have to have a `@ModelAttribute` annotation on each of the parameters in request handler method, otherwise I get an error: `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'registrationFormBean' available as request attribute`.

Here is the source of my controller, and the hack to my problem:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postLoginForm(@ModelAttribute("registrationFormBean") RegistrationFormBean registrationFormBean, @ModelAttribute("loginFormBean") @Valid LoginFormBean loginFormBean, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }
    return "register";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "registeration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postRegisterationForm(@ModelAttribute("loginFormBean") LoginFormBean loginFormBean, @ModelAttribute("registrationFormBean") @Valid RegistrationFormBean registrationFormBean, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }
    return "register";
}
```

**Update:**

The Login form (in a single JSP page):

```
// login form 1        
<sf:form id="redId" action="registration" modelAttribute="registrationFormBean" method="POST"> 
    <sf:input path="firstName" id="fName" />
    <sf:input path="lastName" id="lName" />
    <sf:input path="emailId" id="email" />
</sf:form>

// login form 2
<sf:form action="login" modelAttribute="loginFormBean" method="POST"> 
    <sf:input path="userName" id="userId" />
    <sf:input path="passWord" id="passId" />
</sf:form>
```

Now, if remove either `@ModelAttribute("loginFormBean")` from `postRegisterationForm()` or `@ModelAttribute("registrationFormBean")` from `postLoginForm()`, I get an error as mentioned.

I don't think adding `@ModelAttribute` to every method parameter is a good design as the other don't serve any propose.

What is the correct design?

Comment: can you post your controller ?

Comment: Please consider adding code samples to improve the question.

Comment: can you add the requestMethod.Get for loginform ?